# Get the range index of a number

Tags: javascript, math

I have 3 ranges of numbers:

1. 0-39
2. 40-79
3. 89-119

Given a random number between 0-120 how can I calculate in which range it falls?

For example, given the number 60 I need the result 2.

Edit. The ranges are just an example for the question, but the number of ranges can increase, but the length of the range will always be the same. So I could have 6 ranges each range length 30, or 8 ranges each length of 20 etc.

TIA

Comment: Which programming language? Mathematica?

Comment: @MYGz no, javascript, I am looking for the calculation I need to do, the programming I can handle myself

Comment: @RoryDaulton correct, I updated the question

Comment: That third range should be 80-119?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start numbering your ranges at 1, then 2 and so on. It would be slightly more convenient to have range 0, then 1, and so on. But I'll answer your question as currently given, starting the range-count at 1.

If the random number is n, and your ranges have size r, then the number of the range is, in Python code,

```
(n // r) + 1
```

Note that is an integer division, which is done in different ways in various programming languages. Most languages do not need those parentheses, since order-of-operations will do the division before the addition. I believe that JavaScript would use

```
Math.floor(n / r) + 1;
```

Comment: @Ronnyvdb perhaps you can give it a thumbs up. (i.e. upvote)